# Вывод данных в таблицу react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Здраствуйте, я хочу вывести данные из `json` в таблицу по датам. В `json` есть id (которое тоже хочу вывести) и данные. Вот вид `json`:

```
{
"1": [
    {
        "date_visit": "2021-06-20",
        "presences": true,
        "reason": "null"
    },
    {
        "date_visit": "2021-06-21",
        "presences": true,
        "reason": "null"
    },
    {
        "date_visit": "2021-06-22",
        "presences": true,
        "reason": "null"
    },
    {
        "date_visit": "2021-06-23",
        "presences": true,
        "reason": "null"
    },
    {
        "date_visit": "2021-06-24",
        "presences": true,
        "reason": "null"
    },
    {
        "date_visit": "2021-06-25",
        "presences": true,
        "reason": "null"
    }
],
"4": [
    {
        "date_visit": "2021-06-19",
        "presences": true,
        "reason": "null"
    },
    {
        "date_visit": "2021-06-19",
        "presences": true,
        "reason": "null"
    }
]}
```

Я хочу всё это вывести в таблицу по датам, но не понимаю, как это сделать. Вот мой нынешний код:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Table, TableBody, TableContainer, TableHead, Paper, Checkbox, Select, MenuItem} from '@material-ui/core';
import {StyledTableCell, StyledTableRow, tableStyles} from "./MainTableStyle";
import axios from "axios";
import {API_URL} from "../config";


const columns = [];
// eslint-disable-next-line array-callback-return
Array(/*new Date().getDate()*/ 24).fill(null).map((item, index) => index + 1).map((day, index) => {
    columns.push({id: index, label: day})
})

function MainTable() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    let result = "0";
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const result = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/childrenGroupTable`, {
                headers: {Authorization: localStorage.getItem('token')}
            });

            setData(result.data);
        })();
    }, []);

    result = data.reduce((a, c) => (
        a[c.children_id] ?? (a[c.children_id] = []),
            a[c.children_id].push({
                date_visit: c.date_visit,
                presences: c.presences,
                reason: c.reason
            }),
            a
    ), {})

console.log(result)
    const classes = tableStyles();
    if (Object.keys(result).length === 0) {
        return (<h1 className={classes.table}>Загрузка</h1>)
    }
    return ();
 }

 export default MainTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Данные можно вывести примерно так: проходимся по ключам объекта и далее используя ключ рендерим массивы данных. У меня получилось примерно так:

```js
// import React from "react";

const data = {
  1: [
    {
      date_visit: "2021-06-20",
      presences: true,
      reason: "null",
    },
    {
      date_visit: "2021-06-21",
      presences: true,
      reason: "null",
    },
    {
      date_visit: "2021-06-22",
      presences: true,
      reason: "null",
    },
    {
      date_visit: "2021-06-23",
      presences: true,
      reason: "null",
    },
    {
      date_visit: "2021-06-24",
      presences: true,
      reason: "null",
    },
    {
      date_visit: "2021-06-25",
      presences: true,
      reason: "null",
    },
  ],
  4: [
    {
      date_visit: "2021-06-19",
      presences: true,
      reason: "null",
    },
    {
      date_visit: "2021-06-19",
      presences: true,
      reason: "null",
    },
  ],
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
        return (
          <div key={key}>
            <h3>Key is: {key}</h3>
            {data[key].map(({ date_visit, presences, reason }, idx) => (
              <div 
               key={idx}
               style={{
                 display: "flex",
                 justifyContent: "space-between",
                 width: "600px",
               }}
              >
                <div>date_visit: {date_visit}</div>
                <div>presences: {presences.toString()}</div>
                <div>reason: {reason}</div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

// export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```